# Maya crash in Python script

Tags: python, sockets, crash, maya

I'm new to python, so as I am exploring this I can't execute this program because maya crashes. I don't know what to do more. Everytime I execute this python script in script editor I have to quit maya and restart it, because de program won't respond.
The code I'm using is:

```
import socket

import maya.cmds as cmds

UDP_IP="localhost"

UDP_PORT=6001

sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )

sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while 1:

    data= sock.recv(1024)
    print (data)
    dataSplit=data.split(';')
    print (dataSplit)

    myList=[]
    for i in range (0, len(dataSplit)):
        myList.append(int(dataSplit[i]))
    print(myList)

    cmds.setAttr('ik_root.moveX',myList[0])
    cmds.setAttr('ik_root.moveY',myList[1])
    cmds.setAttr('ik_root.moveZ',myList[2])


    cmds.refresh()
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

The short of it, you have an infinite loop, `while 1:` will always be 1, To fix this, simply remove the while loop, if you do have a condition that you need to perform those tasks on, make sure you update it in the loop, example

```
import socket

import maya.cmds as cmds

UDP_IP="localhost"

UDP_PORT=6001

sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )

sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
apples = 0

while apples = 1:

    data= sock.recv(1024)
    print (data)
    dataSplit=data.split(';')
    print (dataSplit)

    myList=[]
    for i in range (0, len(dataSplit)):
        myList.append(int(dataSplit[i]))
    print(myList)

    cmds.setAttr('ik_root.moveX',myList[0])
    cmds.setAttr('ik_root.moveY',myList[1])
    cmds.setAttr('ik_root.moveZ',myList[2])

    apples = 0



    cmds.refresh()
```

Answer (score 1):

The while loop has no exit, so you'll be stuck in listen-and-process mode forever. Moreover your call to socket.recv is blocking, so you won't be able to interact with maya at all while this script is running - the script will grab the main UI thread (where mel/python runs) and never let it go.

If you want to run an external communications protocol you'll have to learn how maya handles python threads ( docs [here](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2009help/index.html?url=Python_Python_and_threading.htm,topicNumber=d0e178412) ).  If you aren't tied to an external communications protocol you may have better luck using maya's native [commandPort](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/commandPort.html) -- which doesn't do anything special except listen on tcp and trigger scripts, but at least means you don't need to create your own threaded client inside of Maya.  Other good choices for a remoting client are [RPYC](http://www.rpycc.org/club/scripts/public/public.asp) and [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/), both of which will help you create a client without writing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop is what's killing you here. 1 is always 1 so it will run continuously and crash Maya. If you want to make a [generator](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators) to return `data` then do something like:

```
def dataGen():
    while 1:

    data= sock.recv(1024)
    print (data)
    dataSplit=data.split(';')
    yield (dataSplit)

    myList=[]
    for i in range (0, len(dataSplit)):
        myList.append(int(dataSplit[i]))
    yield (myList)

    cmds.setAttr('ik_root.moveX',myList[0])
    cmds.setAttr('ik_root.moveY',myList[1])
    cmds.setAttr('ik_root.moveZ',myList[2])


    cmds.refresh()
```